# Node REPL : Latest Script file contents are not getting fetched using require method

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, require, read-eval-print-loop

While using node js repl to run run `require` command latest file changes are not getting captured.

OS => Windows 11
Node Version => 16.6.0

Let `script.js` has content

```
global.testObject = {};
testObject.cont = "This is sample 1";
```

After accessing the file in node repl using `require('script.js')`, the `testObject` is available in the repl.
Then after changing the file content say to

```
global.testObject = {};
testObject.cont = "This is an updated sample 2";
```

Running `require('script.js')` again. But the `cont` of `testObject` is not getting updated in repl.

Does anyone know the reason and how to make latest changes available in the repl using `require`.

Comment: Don't set things on `global`. All `require()` calls are cached, you just require the same thing in two different places, and both places get the same export. It also means you can't "re-require" something unless you first manually bust the require cache, which you shouldn't ever need to do except in pretty much a single use-case I can think of, so: what's your use-case? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you so much for the replay. I was attempting to build a custom node js code debugger with electron UI and node repl. 

I will try to copy the script contents to, may be a temp file and and then try to require the same again.

Comment: Before you continue on that: are you aware [that `node inspect` exists](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)? Because there's not a lot of reason to implement your own debugger when Node already has that built in, being guaranteed better than what you could come up with =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am not aware of `node inspect`. Let me go through the doc for that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input. As a work around one can try to clear specific file entry from the require cache as below.

```
delete require.cache["Absolute path to previously required file"].
```

Then try to require the same file again. Which will reflect the latest changes to the file.

Though not sure if there is any serious performance/function issues.

Answer (score 1):

First time you require('script.js) the script is executed. Second time you require('script.js') it will not execute it. This is the way nodeJs works. if your script exports something, the first time you require it will be cached and the second be recovered from the cache.